# grep "?" does not match valid matches

Tags: grep

I want to match tags in files (with optional brackets) ... easy one would think ... the regex is something like `^\[?MyTag\]?`. But ... Grep doesn't like it. None of the lines that would be valid matches are actually matched.

The interesting part is: if I replace the `?` with a `*` (so zero to infinite matches, not zero or one) it matches everything like it should, but really that would mean the feature is broken and I don't believe that.

Any input?

Using grep (GNU grep) 2.22 on Windows.

PS: so grep is like this ...

```
grep -e "^\[?MyTag\]?" file.txt
```

and my test file is like this

```
[MyTag] hello
NotMyTag ugly
[NotMyTag] dumb
MyTag world
```

which obviously should result in 1st and 4th line showing but shows nothing.

Comment: ? only matches one character, right? so try [xMyTag]. I suspect that will match.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/a/23199/297512

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't - try to read more carefully.

Comment: @Almo correct, zero or one matches, so \[?Bla must match both Bla and [Bla but not [[Bla. And that's exactly what the regex does, but obviously grep does not like it.

Comment: Fair enough. Working on solution.

Comment: I've been working around this issue for years. Finally motivated me to look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` is not part of the basic regular expressions, which grep supports. GNU grep supports them as an extension, but you have to escape them:

```
$ grep '^\[\?MyTag\]\?' file.txt
[MyTag] hello
MyTag world
```

Or, as pointed out, use `grep -E` to enable extended regular expressions.

For GNU grep, the only difference between `grep` and `grep -E`, i.e., using basic and extended regular expressions, is what you have to escape and what not.

- Basic regular expressions

  - Capture groups and quantifying have to be escaped: `\( \)` and `\{ \}`
  - Zero or one (`?`), one or more (`+`) and alternation (`|`) are not part of BRE, but supported by GNU grep as an extension (but need to be escaped: `\? \+ \|`)
- Extended regular expressions

  - Capture groups and quantifying don't have to be escaped: `( )` and `{ }`
  - `?`, `+` and `|` are supported and don't need be be escaped

Comment: Ah, that's an actually good response (regarding escaping), thanks :)

Comment: `-r` is recursive mode, no?

Answer (score 3):

First off, `?` is not supported in vanilla `grep`, so you need to use the `-E` flag to enable extended regex. You can easily verify this by running `grep '?' <<< 'a'` and `grep -E '?' <<< 'a'`. Only the latter will match. `-e` just explicitly indicates what your regex is. It is not the same as `-E`.

Your initial command works fine if you change the `-e` to upper case:

```
grep -E '^\[?MyTag\]?'
```

Example:

```
$ grep -E '^\[?MyTag\]?' <<< '[MyTag] hello
> NotMyTag ugly
> [NotMyTag] dumb
> MyTag world'
```

Output:

```
[MyTag] hello
MyTag world
```

Credit goes to the answers of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/23197/297512) on SuperUser.

Comment: Lol, #quality. Also [documentation claims it does](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) so also #docquality -.-

Comment: @FrankyBoy. I don't get the #quality references.

Comment: both the lack of support as well as claiming it works in the docs. Really, hardly ever saw such an essential tool so badly documented.

Comment: I've definitely seen it used as an example of how not to write man-pages, although some of the later linux versions are a bit better. Not sure why you picked my answer over @BenjaminW.'s tho. His is clearly better, especially since you are using GNU grep.

Comment: ah, that got unselected again ... dumb stackoverflow ... two good answers and I got to pick one ;)