# grep ".*" does not match valid matches?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

### Information and Problems

I am learning linux command now, and was simply practicing grep command in a bash.
I want to match every file whose name begins with character "a"...quite a simple requirement...From what I understand the regex should be something like `a.*`, but it doesn't work as what I thought.

**Some of the filenames should be matched doesn't match.**

### My Command

I typed commands in a Ubuntu Mate 16.04 VirtualBox terminal.
I have created a document called test. In the test document, I have got three files,

- `a.txt`
- `a1.txt`
- `a2.txt`

Here the following is my command using grep.

```
ls -a | grep -E -e a.*
```

But the output is simply

```
a.txt
```

I think `.*` should mean any numbers of whatever character. So the `a1.txt` and `a2.txt` should match the regex, but it doesn't work.
However if I tried

```
ls -a | grep -E -e ^a.*
ls -a | grep -E -e a.+
```

Both of the command work as what I expected, all the filenames matches.

```
a.txt  
a1.txt
a2.txt
```

I could not figure out what goes wrong?

### What I have tried

I have searched through the questions, there exist a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129300/grep-does-not-match-valid-matches) very similar to mine, but the problems is about the extended grep and the basic one, which definitely isn't my situation.

Comment: not an answer: use `find`

Comment: Please consider using code syntax for code (as with four literal spaces, or the `{}` button in the editor), rather than rolling your own combination of quoted-text syntax and bolding.

Comment: Also, I hope that you don't *actually* mean to use this with `ls`, which [should not be used programatically](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Am not sure why I was down voted? mis-interpetations are meant to occur, OP did explicitly  say `grep` but his requirement needed `find`? Have any sane explanation to this?

Comment: PS: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically recognized [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2062).

Comment: @Inian, if I had to guess (and to be clear, I'm just guessing), I'd say it's because this didn't actually answer the literal question about `grep`; if the OP was just using `ls` as a source of sample input, as opposed to really talking about matching files, then that answer would have been entirely nonresponsive -- and it was short enough to productively be something that could be put in a comment, thus communicating the relevant intent just as clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use more [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)!

With the literal command you ran in your question:

```
ls -a | grep -E -e a.*
```

...your **shell** will replace `a.*` with a list of filenames in the current directory matching `a.*` as a [glob pattern](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) before `grep` is started at all. (See also the full [bash-hackers page on globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs)).

---

If `a.*` is placed inside quotes, as in:

```
ls -a | grep -E 'a.*'
```

...then this string will no longer be evaluated as a glob. You might also want to *anchor* the regex with `^`, to search only at the beginning:

```
ls -a | grep -E '^a.*'
```

---

That said, `ls` is [not a tool build for programmatic use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- it isn't guaranteed to emit filenames in unmodified literal form, so it's not certain that all possible names will be emitted in such a way that `grep` or other tools will parse them correctly (indeed, `ls` *can't* emit all possible names is literal form, since it uses newline delimiters between names, whereas newline literals are actually possible within names themselves). Consider [using `find`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for this kind of processing:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf 'Found file: %q\n' "$filename"
done < <(find . -regex '/^a[^/]*' -print0)
```

...will work even with files having intentionally difficult-to-process names; consider, for example, `mkdir -p $'\n/etc/passwd\n' && touch $'\n/etc/passwd\n/a.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding how the shell is parsing your command. When you do this:

```
ls -a | grep -E -e a.*
```

The shell globs the command *before* it is passed to `ls` or `grep`. The result of the glob is this:

```
ls -a | grep -E -e a.txt
```

Because in globbing, `a.*` only matches `a.txt`.

You need to put the regexes in quotes, e.g.

```
ls -a | grep -E -e 'a.*'
```

Comment: Think I beat you there by... 20 seconds?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is off-topic, this is not [race-condition] :)

Comment: (That said, *this particular* off-topic chatter exists to make it clear to others why I don't delete my answer despite it containing strictly-duplicative contents, which is what I'd normally do if someone posted something covering all the same ground before me and I didn't have significant enhancements pending that would improve my answer's value or cover additional ground).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good Job!...Orz..That's too fast...and I didn't realize that this is the problem of 'ls', probably I should search it more throughly....

Comment: @CieloWu, to be clear, it's not `ls` in particular -- the shell performs globbing of unquoted arguments before *any* command is run; the command itself has no control over that behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, thanks for clarifying! Sorry that I'm not so familiar with Markdown now.